# Password Verify alway returning a false value?

Tags: php

I am currently trying to set up a login page for my website that I am creating as part of my college course. I can create an account on the website with a hashed password just fine. The hashed password shows up as:

```
$2y$10$c17e2YWOPrzZy8RNLZo9Yejm0vHebwhdkD7tyzBgMcIiu6zO5XVn2
```

I have searched solutions such as checking to see if the hashed password is 60 characters and other solutions which have been unsuccessful, I have also asked two other college lecturers and classmates but none of them have been able to help.

My code is:

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    echo $username;
    echo " "; 
    echo $password;
    echo " "; 

    $sql = "SELECT userno, email, password FROM Users WHERE username = '$username';";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo $sql;
    if ($result->num_rows == 1){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if (password_verify( $password, $row["password"]))
        {
            echo "<br/> Welcome back to Ryan's Review Website!";
            echo "<br/> You have succsesfuly logged in!";

            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
            $_SESSION["userno"] = $row['userno'];
        }
        else {
            echo "<br/>Sorry, It seems that either you do not have an account or you have mistyped your username and/or password";
            echo "<br/><a href='Sign In.html'>Click Here</a> to try again!";
            echo "<br/><a href='Register.html'>Click Here</a> if you do not have an account!";
        }
    }
    $conn->close();

?>
```

My biggest issue with this is that it was based off working code I have used on a previous website last year, where it worked successfully. However when I used the exact same code here (with table and variable names changed to match the new database) it always returns a false value.

EDIT: Here is my code for adding a new user to the database:

```
$details = [];
$details ['username'] = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$details ['email'] = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; 
$password ['password1'] = isset($_POST['password1']) ? $_POST['password1'] : '';    
$hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT );


$sql = "INSERT INTO Users ";
$sql .= "(username, email, password) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (";
$sql .= "'" . $details['username'] . "',";
$sql .= "'" . $details['email'] . "',";
$sql .= "'" . $hash . "'";
$sql .= ")";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    
echo "Congratulations! You have now joined Ryan's Review Website!";
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection - you should fix that :)

Comment: Which datatype did you use for your password?

Comment: When you store the password, did you use `password_hash()`?

Comment: please also show how you stored the password

Comment: I think u forgot to hash password from POST

Comment: @YuraRosiak that's not how password_verify works.

Comment: @Jeff Sorry) never used it before

Comment: if you are having problems with `password_hash()`, try using `hash_equals()`

Comment: I dont see anything wrong in the code only that is open to sql injection , he probably has his datatype on `varcher(25)` or something else, he needs to change that to `char(60)`

Comment: ['*Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).*' / 'The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE on failure.'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Its already stored as CHAR(60), I have also tried VARCHAR(255) and VARCHAR(60). Neither worked unfortunately

Comment: Storing hashed of arrays is not recommended and may give unexpected results

Comment: so change `$password ['password1'] = ..` to `$password = ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misstake when saving the password hash in these lines:

```
$password ['password1'] = isset($_POST['password1']) ? $_POST['password1'] : '';    
$hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT );
```

Here you actually try to hash the array `$password`, which will throw a

> WARNING: expected param 1 to be string, array given

Depending on your settings you might not see this warning (and the following) and store something wrong in your database.

So change

```
$password ['password1'] = isset($_POST['password1']) ? $_POST['password1'] : '';
```

to

```
$password = isset($_POST['password1']) ? $_POST['password1'] : '';
```

Comment: Thank you, this issue has been bugging me for ages. The issue being on my registration page and not my log in page explains how it got unnoticed for so long. As for the warning, I never saw it, but it will definitely be good to take a note of it for future reference.